# Query with column named "name"

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1267

I am trying to join a few tables but it is failing on my join statement. I believe it is because the column name in the second join is "name" and perhaps MySQL thinks i am trying to access an attribute? how can i get around this?

```
SELECT surgery_city.*, s.surgeon_type, st.abbrev
FROM surgery_city 
LEFT JOIN surgery_key as s ON s.surg_id = treatment_id 
LEFT JOIN states as st ON st.name = surgery_city.state
WHERE treatment_id='10001'
```

The issue is the second left join where i reference st.name - any ideas on how i can reference that column properly? changing the column name in the table is not an option at this point unfortunately :(..

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

**UPDATE:**

The error I get on the query above is:

[Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

when i surround the field by back ticks i get the following:

```
LEFT JOIN states as st ON `st.name` = seo_surgery_city.state
```

I get the following instead:

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'st.name' in 'on clause'

It also fails on

```
LEFT JOIN states as st ON st.`name` = seo_surgery_city.state
```

(single quotes = back ticks there, but it wont display properly here)

[Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Also fails on

```
LEFT JOIN states as st ON `st`.`name` = seo_surgery_city.state
```

[Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: Can you tell us how it's failing?  Are you getting an error?  What error?

Comment: name is a keyword. Enclose st.name in backticks.

Comment: @MouseFood You sure about that? [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @MouseFood I didn't see `name` is a keyword in [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should embrace the column name with backticks:

```
st.`name`
```

**UPD**

The problem is that the columns have different collations, try the following:

```
SELECT surgery_city.*, s.surgeon_type, st.abbrev
FROM surgery_city 
LEFT JOIN surgery_key as s ON s.surg_id = treatment_id 
LEFT JOIN states as st ON st.name = (surgery_city.state COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)
WHERE treatment_id='10001'
```

But to fix this you should update the collation for one of the columns: `states.name` or `seo_surgery_city.state`. They should both have `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: adding the collate function worked, no back ticks required .. thank you very much.

Comment: @Silvertiger, I am glad. But if you can, you should better update the column definition in `st.name` to `utf8_general_ci` =)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the column name in backquotes, like **`st.name`**.  [See the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: @Shiplu: Because the OP did not include the error message, I can only infer what the problem is.  You can't honestly say "I know the solution to your problem even though you didn't tell me what it is yet".

Comment: the suggestion in not correct anyway =), only the column name should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You should **use same collation and charset to all table and columns**. If you dont know what collation to use, use `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8` charset.

```
ALTER TABLE seo_surgery_city CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
ALTER TABLE seo_surgery_key CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
ALTER TABLE states CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Comment: [SQL] ALTER TABLE seo_surgery_city CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
[Err] 1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022:**

The keyword **"name"** is now listed on the **"keywords and reserved words"** list of the official MySQL documentation. You can find all the reserved words there.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N